# What http status code should I return if the challenge that is returned from the client does not match the server-side generated challenge?

Tags: http, https, webauthn

One of the requirements for WebAuthn is that I need to verify that the challenge that is returned by the client matches the challenge that the server generated for the client. If the
challenge that the client returned does not match the challenge that the server generated,
then what HTTP status code should I return?

Comment: I'd say 403, since failure to meet the challenge expectations implies failure to authenticate.

Comment: @datenwolf You should submit that as an answer

Comment: @IAmKale: I would, if I were 100% sure, that this is the correct behavior. I'd rather see what people more knowledgeable in those matters have to say. Hence comment, not "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can approach this one of two ways:

#### HTTP 400 Bad Request

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (for example, malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Through this lens the WebAuthn response that was submitted could be considered "malformed" because it didn't possess the expected value (the challenge). Thus the input data constitutes a bad request, and if the user can resubmit a valid response then the request will be accepted.

#### HTTP 403 Forbidden

[As per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403):

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

I thought I might be able to rationalize using HTTP 403, but this error code is more relevant for post-authentication *authorization* violations (e.g. a non-admin trying to access an admin-only endpoint.) Considering the fact that you don't know who the user is yet to know what resources they can access, I don't think this makes much sense to use here.